# Bash brace expansion doesn't work in an export statement

Tags: bash, variable, brace-expansion

Consider the following example:

```
$ echo file_{a,b,c}
file_a file_b file_c         # brace expansion worked :)

$ export VARIABLE=file_{a,b,c}
$ echo $VARIABLE
file_c                       # brace expansion didn't work :(
```

How come that if I echo `file_{a,b,c}` directly, the brace expansion prints the name of all three files, while if I assign the same expression to a variable and echo that, it only prints the name of file_c?

And is there a different way to assign a brace-expanded string to a variable that would work in my case?

Comment: Are you expecting the `VARIABLE` variable to contain a single string with the value `file_a file_b file_c`?  Are you not looking to create a list (`list=( file_{a,b,c} ); echo "${list[@]}"`)?  Are you exporting the variable for any particular purpose (some other process needs to read it in its environment), or is it just a habit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it with `set -x` to see what happens:

```
$ set -x
$ export VARIABLE=file_{a,b,c}
+ export VARIABLE=file_a VARIABLE=file_b VARIABLE=file_c
+ VARIABLE=file_a
+ VARIABLE=file_b
+ VARIABLE=file_c
```

You end up assigning the different values to the same variable, and each overrides the earlier value.

I think brace expansion only works in a "list context", so it's hard to use it for generating a single string. Unless with something like `string=$(echo file_{a,b,c})`.

If you do the same without `export`, i.e. `VARIABLE=file_{a,b,c}` it just assigns the unexpanded value, same as `VARIABLE='file_{a,b,c}'`. But if you do `export VARIABLE=$foo`, then `$foo` does *not* get word-split. Those assignment-builtins like `export`, and `readonly` etc. are a bit odd. (This is in Bash, that is. I didn't test other shells.)

But, note that a space-separated string (if that's what you're thinking anyway) is not an optimal way to store distinct values, mostly since you can't store e.g. filenames that themselves contain spaces.

If you can, and it depends on what you're doing, you might want to consider using an array instead.

```
$ arr=( file_{a,b,c} )
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
file_b
$ printf "<%s>\n" "${arr[@]}"
<file_a>
<file_b>
<file_c>
```

Comment: except of course you were using `export`, and you can't export an array to the environment, so they're not likely to help there.